# Get Contextmenu's Parent Control. WPF app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, contextmenu

I have a ComboBox control inside Context menu for some Label Control that I have added in Code behind in wpf application.  There are many Labels on the page that have Contextmenu. Basically it is like this **LABEL contains ContextMenu** and **ContextMenu conntains Combobox**. On Combobox's SelectionChanged event I want to know which label's contextmenu's Combobox has generated this event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the ComboBox from the `sender` argument in the eventhandler.

You can then get the ContextMenu from the `Parent` property on the ComboBox.

And then finally the Label from the `PlacementTarget` property on the ContextMenu.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var label = new Label();
        label.Content = "Click me!";
        label.Name = "clickMe";
        this.Content = label;

        var cmb = new ComboBox();
        cmb.Name = "combobox1";
        cmb.Items.Add("Test1");
        cmb.Items.Add("Test2");
        cmb.Items.Add("Test3");
        cmb.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(cmb_SelectionChanged);

        var menu = new ContextMenu();
        menu.Name = "contextmenu";
        menu.Items.Add(cmb);

        label.ContextMenu = menu;
    }

    private void cmb_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
        var contextmenu = (ContextMenu)cmb.Parent;
        var label = (Label)contextmenu.PlacementTarget;

        MessageBox.Show("Combobox: " + cmb.Name + Environment.NewLine +
                        "Contextmenu: " + contextmenu.Name + Environment.NewLine +
                        "Label: " + label.Name);
    }
}
```